# How to create react native app in version 0.60.0 without cocoapod?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

When I create react-native application with latest version 0.60.0. It is creating application with cocoapod setup. How to create application without cocoapod? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same here. We don't want to use Cocoapods in our project as well since it is very big and can be painful for us to use it

Comment: @O.Borcuhin Yeah and it's giving too many dependency by default. :(